# JSONParseException reading data using Kafka rest API

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-rest

**KAFKA TOPIC (test3)**

```
$ kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server broker:9092 --topic test3 --from-beginning

"Can we write to a topic that does not exist?"
"Can we write to a topic that does not exist?"
{"foo":"bar"}
["foo","bar"]
confluent
confluent
confluent
kafka
logs


0

0
```

**Consumer (kafka-rest API on `localhost:8082`)**

1. Create a consumer `POST` request to `http://localhost:8082/consumers/rested`

Request Body:

```
 {
   "format": "json",
   "auto.offset.reset": "earliest",
   "auto.commit.enable": "false"
 }
```

Response Body:

```
{
   "instance_id": "rest-consumer-dfa6ee0e-4f24-46dc-b0dc-dda3b80866ff",

   "base_uri": "http://rest-proxy:8082/consumers/rested/instances/rest-consumer-dfa6ee0e-4f24-46dc-b0dc-dda3b80866ff"

}
```

2. Create a subscription usihg `POST` to `http://localhost:8082/consumers/rested/instances/rest-consumer-dfa6ee0e-4f24-46dc-b0dc-dda3b80866ff/subscription`

using Headers:

```
Host: http://localhost:8082
Content-Type: application/vnd.kafka.v2+json
```

and Request Body:

```
{
    "topics": [
      "test3"
    ]
}
```

returns a Response of `204 No Content`.

3. Read records by making a `GET` request to `http://localhost:8082/consumers/rested/instances/rest-consumer-dfa6ee0e-4f24-46dc-b0dc-dda3b80866ff/records`

using the Headers:

```
Host: http://localhost:8082
Accept: application/vnd.kafka.json.v2+json
```

returns the Response:

```
{
    "error_code": 50002,
    "message": "Kafka error: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'key': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')\n at [Source: (byte[])\"key\"; line: 1, column: 7]"
}
```

How can we fix this issue and ensure that we receive the data?

**Exception (on Kafka)**

The running Kafka Rest Proxy server log has the following exception:

```
rest-proxy         | [2018-12-31 03:09:27,232] INFO 172.25.0.1 - - [31/Dec/2018:03:09:26 +0000] "GET /consumers/rest-consumer/instances/rest-consumer-8e49873e-13ce-46a5-be1f-0237a0369efe/records HTTP/1.1" 500 211  341 (io.confluent.rest-utils.requests)
rest-proxy         | [2018-12-31 03:09:27,235] ERROR Unexpected exception in consumer read task id=io.confluent.kafkarest.v2.KafkaConsumerReadTask@59611e28  (io.confluent.kafkarest.v2.KafkaConsumerReadTask)
rest-proxy         | org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'key': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
rest-proxy         |  at [Source: (byte[])"key"; line: 1, column: 7]
rest-proxy         | Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'key': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
rest-proxy         |  at [Source: (byte[])"key"; line: 1, column: 7]
rest-proxy         |    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1804)
rest-proxy         |    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:679)
rest-proxy         |    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._reportInvalidToken(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:3526)
rest-proxy         |    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._handleUnexpectedValue(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:2621)
rest-proxy         |    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._nextTokenNotInObject(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:826)
rest-proxy         |    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.nextToken(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:723)
rest-proxy         |    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:4141)
rest-proxy         |    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4000)
rest-proxy         |    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3091)
rest-proxy         |    at io.confluent.kafkarest.v2.JsonKafkaConsumerState.deserialize(JsonKafkaConsumerState.java:79)
rest-proxy         |    at io.confluent.kafkarest.v2.JsonKafkaConsumerState.createConsumerRecord(JsonKafkaConsumerState.java:64)
rest-proxy         |    at io.confluent.kafkarest.v2.KafkaConsumerReadTask.maybeAddRecord(KafkaConsumerReadTask.java:158)
rest-proxy         |    at io.confluent.kafkarest.v2.KafkaConsumerReadTask.addRecords(KafkaConsumerReadTask.java:142)
rest-proxy         |    at io.confluent.kafkarest.v2.KafkaConsumerReadTask.doPartialRead(KafkaConsumerReadTask.java:99)
rest-proxy         |    at io.confluent.kafkarest.v2.KafkaConsumerManager$RunnableReadTask.run(KafkaConsumerManager.java:370)
rest-proxy         |    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
rest-proxy         |    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
rest-proxy         |    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
rest-proxy         |    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
rest-proxy         |    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

**Consumer-Groups CLI**

I can view the consumer-group on the CLI but it has no active members:

```
$ kafka-consumer-groups --bootstrap-server broker:9092 --list
```

has the result:

```
console-consumer-60695
console-consumer-62259
console-consumer-19307
console-consumer-47906
console-consumer-40838
rested
```

However, when I attempt to retrieve the `members`:

```
$ kafka-consumer-groups --bootstrap-server localhost:29092 --group rest-consumer --describe --members

Consumer group 'rested' has no active members.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR**

You need to wrap your key in double-quotes, Not because all keys need to be wrapped in quotes but with a JSON parser you need to make your key valid JSON and a string wrapped in double-quotes is valid JSON.

If you really need to process this message you would need to read it in a different format than JSON.

**Long Answer**

You have a record with a key that does not have quotes which makes the value invalid JSON so when the Jackson JSON parser tries to parse the key it's not valid JSON (which isn't clear from the error message but when it doesn't see a quote or a square or curly bracket it starts to assume it's a boolean or null).

You can see where it's grabbing they key and trying to decode it as JSON here

> https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-rest/blob/a9b7cc527a26fdf09db27d148f2e71bfe3d87a6a/kafka-rest/src/main/java/io/confluent/kafkarest/v2/JsonKafkaConsumerState.java#L69

I was able to reproduce your error using this method

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.kafka.v2+json" \
      --data '{"name": "my_consumer_instance", "format": "json", "auto.offset.reset": "latest"}' \
      http://localhost:8082/consumers/my_json_consumer

curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.kafka.v2+json" --data '{"topics":["testjsontopic"]}' \
 http://localhost:8082/consumers/my_json_consumer/instances/my_consumer_instance/subscription


./bin/kafka-console-producer \
  --broker-list :9092 \
  --topic testjsontopic \
  --property parse.key=true \
  --property key.separator="&"

>"key"&{"foo":"bar"}

*Ctrl-C

curl -X GET -H "Accept: application/vnd.kafka.json.v2+json" \
      http://localhost:8082/consumers/my_json_consumer/instances/my_consumer_instance/records
```

At this point I am able to read the record but when I add a key without the quotes I get the same error as you

```
./bin/kafka-console-producer \
  --broker-list :9092 \
  --topic testjsontopic \
  --property parse.key=true \
  --property key.separator="&"

>key&{"foo":"bar"}
```

Now when I call this code

```
curl -X GET -H "Accept: application/vnd.kafka.json.v2+json" \
      http://localhost:8082/consumers/my_json_consumer/instances/my_consumer_instance/records
```

Now I receive this error

> com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token
>   'key': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')

Use this to read your topics keys also

```
./bin/kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic testjsontopic --property print.key=true --from-beginning
```

Comment: The `confluent 5.1.0 docker container` was keeping track of topics when we close them. It could be the latter rather than the former. So, I deleted the topics using the `kafka-topics` CLI and it worked correctly.

Comment: I have the same problem. If I want to consume logs without key having quotes via `kafka-rest`,  I use `binary` format(`application/vnd.kafka.binary.v2+json`) to read them,   but how to get the real value from binary format ?  

(ps: I use python requests to query kafka-rest)